# nuget uninstall packages vs SVN working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, nuget

Good day!

I'm starting with NuGet 1.2 on VS2010 Express. I use SVN for my projects (without integration into VS, just TortoiseSVN). The question is -- it seems that NuGet creates folder `/packages/` in the root of the solution. It seems that while uninstalling a package NuGet will remove the package folder. This will break the SVN working copy.

Any guidelines on SVN and NuGet working together?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**: I don't mean that the whole `/packages/` folder is removed, I mean that, for example when upgrading T4MVC to 2.6.45 folder `/packages/T4MVC.2.6.44` (along with .svn folder inside) will be removed and this will break SVN working copy.

**Update 2**: As I checked -- NuGet doesn't delete folders if something not belonging to package is inside it (`.svn` folder in my case). So if you prefer to store `packages` in SVN like I do -- after upgrade you should delete folder left from older version of the package from SVN.

Comment: Oh god, that's awful. Maybe this should be reported to the NuGet team. If there is something left in the packages directory, NuGet should leave it there. Or at least fail gracefully.

Comment: Wait, I think it is there already: issue [#810](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/810).

Comment: Please check the update above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to run NuGet without checking in the Packages Folder. You would just exclude the whole folder from SVN and follow the steps outlined in David Ebbo's post: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html

Comment: The problem is that I'm the one of those who "create a ‘Lib’ or ‘ExternalDependencies’ folder, dump binaries into there and commit them to source control to allow others to build." I just want to commit Packages folder, but it seems the first package update will broke my working copy :( Will NuGet left old package version directory intact if it finds `.svn` inside it?

Comment: We do not delete the folder if there are additional files in the folder so having a .svn folder in there would cause us not to delete the folder.

What should be less pain full is to not check-in the packages folder and have people run a the command to install packages before they can build. The post even has a way to add it to MSbuild so it is just magical.

Comment: I prefer to keep all dependencies in SVN just in case when I'm off-line, but have access to SVN server. Anyway I've checked myself -- NuGet doesn't delete folders of older packages with `.svn` inside.

Comment: Updated info: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/easy-way-to-set-up-nuget-to-restore.html